# How to make bootstrap form-inline Horizontal scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My form is way too large I want to make it `scrollable` without breaking line. How can I do this?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="item_group">
   <div class="form-group form-md-line-input" style="">
      <label>Item</label>
      <select class="form-control " data-live-search="true" name="" id="" style="">
         <option>Select Item</option>
         <option value="23">Styler King 6 Card Holder  (Set of 1, Khaki)</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-md-line-input" style="">
      <label>Unit</label>
      <select class="form-control " data-live-search="true" name="" id="" style="">
         <option>Select Unit</option>
         <option value="1">Piece</option>
         <option value="2">Box</option>
         <option value="4">Sub Box</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form_control_1" name="" style="" value="0">
      <label for="form_control_1">Quantity</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form_control_1" name="" style="" value="0">
      <label for="form_control_1">Sale Rate</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form_control_1" name="" style="" value="0">
      <label for="form_control_1">Discount</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form_control_1" name="" style="" value="0">
      <label for="form_control_1">CGST</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form_control_1" name="" style="" value="0">
      <label for="form_control_1">SGST</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form_control_1" name="" style="" value="0">
      <label for="form_control_1">IGST</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form_control_1" name="" style="" value="0">
      <label for="form_control_1">Net Rate</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form_control_1" name="" style="" value="0">
      <label for="form_control_1">Net Amount</label>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_item"> 
   <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px">
      <div class="form-actions noborder">
         <button class="btn blue" style="width: 100%;" onclick="addnewitem()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New Item</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**URL:**

http://vsss.co.in/Admin/index.php/Sales

**Inline Form Image**

[image]

Comment: Do you want horizontal scroll to your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want horizontal scroll to you form, Then add this 
`overflow: scroll; height: 400px;` to this class `.portlet.light`

As per your code,

```
.portlet.light {
padding: 12px 20px 15px;
background-color: #fff;
overflow: scroll;
height: 400px;
}
```